# setting background image css with rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, image

I have an image called item8 that is being rendered on my webpage the css looks like this. This is in a css.sass file

```
.body-detail-intro {
    background: url(/assets/item8-45411322696feaa47a0345b3e4bdd5de1b2cff8243c534b84a83a8d4d732ec0d.png)  no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;

    height: 55vh;
    position: center;
    color: white;
  }
```

I am not sure where there hash on the image path came from as the image is just named item-8. When I remove the hash and just use item-8 the picture still loads.

Now enter this image  Suitsandtables_HowitWorks.png

the code below doesn't work with Suitsandtables_HowitWorks.png I also tried it with another image I have already on my site called team-1 which still didn't work

```
 .middle .right{
      background: image-url("/assets/team-1.jpg") no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
      background-position: center;
      height: 600px;
      width: 300px;
    }
```

Ive tried background, background-image, url, image-url nothing is working. Might be a css issue which I am currently checking as in wrong classes called for the css to hook to but I don't think so.

I am using css.sass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That hash come from `rake assets:precompile`, which is run by default in production so your server or the CDN you're using are able to cache it.

Sprockets will handle that hash for you under the covers.

My file extension is only .scss, but that shouldn't matter.

```
.your-class {
  // Note i'm using only the image name. No path
  background-image: image-url('my_image.jpg');
}
```

I just extracted this example from a working project, so it should work just fine.